Copy cell values to another worksheet based on cell value
I am trying to copy cell value (A641) from Sheet("WIP") to Sheet("Report") (A3), if (N641) from Sheet("WIP") is a specific value ("text").
I want a loop to check the whole column N (from 641 to the bottom.).
The main table keeps expanding so I want to check to the end of column N every time I run it.
I copied the below from another thread and played around but it is not what I want.
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long

    Set wip = Sheets("WIP")
    Set report = Sheets("Report")

    lastRow = wip.Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 641 To lastRow
       
        If wip.Range("N" & i).Value = "test" Then
          
            report.Range("A" & i - 638).Value = wip.Range("A" & i).Value
            
        End If
    Next i
End Sub



its not what i want doesn't provide any information. Pls describe the issue you are encountering with your code. to check the whole column N (below 641 too) What does "whole column N" mean? Do you expect to search from row 1 or row 641 to the bottom row?

Something like this should do it:
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long, wip As Worksheet, report As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook, v, c As Range

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 'or (eg) ThisWorkbook
    Set wip = wb.Worksheets("WIP")
    Set report = wb.Worksheets("Report")

    lastRow = wip.Cells(wip.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
    Set c = report.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1) 'first destination cell
    
    For i = 641 To lastRow
        If wip.Range("N" & i).Value = "test" Then
            v = wip.Range("A" & i).Value 'ColA value
            If Len(v) > 0 Then           'anything to copy?
                c.Value = v              'copy value
                Set c = c.Offset(1)      'next destination cell
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub


hi Tim. Much, much appreciated yr reply. I am almost there it seems. One thing only, this code pastes the relevant info in A33, rather than A3. Any reason as to why? FYI, I have info already in the destination sheet (report), A1, A2, A8, A14, A20, A26 and A32. (i will go into a bit more detail here on what i try to do. A2 will be "test" so i want yr info to start going from A3 downwards. In the future, i will expand yr code to search for another item ("test2") in the initial N column (wip), which i will paste into A9 downwards (A8 is "test2" now, A14 "test3" etc).

Ok. i got it. i fixed this by playing with the offset value, basically having negative offset values pushes upwards. Thanks a lot Tim. You are a star
